# how to show all result query even though the results are empty

Tags: mysql, sql

I count my data from database, but I have a problem with the result. the result only displays data that is not empty, while the empty data is not displayed. how do I display data rows that are empty and not empty?

the result of my query like this

```
pendidikan| Male | Famale | Total
----------+------+--------+------
    SD    |  3   |   4    |  7
   SMP    |  2   |   1    |  3
   SMA    |  1   |   3    |  4
    S1    |  10  |   1    |  11
```

BUT i want the result like this :

```
pendidikan| Male | Famale | Total
----------+------+--------+------
    SD    |  3   |   4    |  7
   SMP    |  2   |   1    |  3
   SMA    |  1   |   3    |  4
    S1    |  10  |   1    |  11
    S2    |  0   |   0    |  0
    S3    |  0   |   0    |  0
```

i want to show empty data from my database. this is my query

```
SELECT a.NamaStatusPendidikan, COUNT(c.IDPencaker) as total,
count(case when c.JenisKelamin='0' then 1 end) as laki,
count(case when c.JenisKelamin='1' then 1 end) as cewe 
FROM msstatuspendidikan as a JOIN mspencaker as c ON
a.IDStatusPendidikan = c.IDStatusPendidikan JOIN 
mspengalaman as d ON c.IDPencaker = d.IDPencaker 
WHERE d.StatusPekerjaan = '0' AND c.RegisterDate 
BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-03-01' GROUP BY a.IDStatusPendidikan
```

Comment: try to use `left join`

Comment: try to use `http://sqlfiddle.com/` website to ask this kind of question so we can answer you fast

Comment: the result remains the same

Comment: Please, provide dummy data with structure Although, with the first view, it seems you should use LEFT OUTER JOIN so you could get at least all the records from msstatuspendidikan table

Comment: Do your table "msstatuspendidikan" contain value S2 and S3 for the date range '2019-01-01' AND '2019-03-01'? or not there as well?

Comment: @mkRabbani yes ```msstatuspendidikan``` contain value S2 and S3, but the data for S2 and S3 is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this query:

```
SELECT sp.NamaStatusPendidikan, 
       COUNT(*) as total,
       SUM( p.JenisKelamin = 0 ) as laki,
       SUM( p.JenisKelamin = 1 ) as cewe 
FROM msstatuspendidikan sp LEFT JOIN
     mspencaker p
     ON sp.IDStatusPendidikan = p.IDStatusPendidikan AND
        p.RegisterDate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-03-01' LEFT JOIN 
     mspengalaman g
     ON g.IDPencaker = c.IDPencaker AND
        g.StatusPekerjaan = 0
GROUP BY sp.IDStatusPendidikan;
```

Notes:

- The `JOIN`s have been replaced with `LEFT JOIN`s.
- Filtering conditions on all but the first table have been moved to the `ON` clauses.
- This replaces the meaningless table aliases with table abbreviations, so the table is easier to read.
- Things that looks like numbers probably are numbers, so I removed the single quotes.
- This simplifies the counts, using the fact that MySQL treats booleans as numbers in a numeric context.